# How do I split a string in half without using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, string

I want to type in a string, which always has a even amount of letters in it. I want it to print out the string but devide in half and connected with "-" in between. I manage to print out the first half of the word, but not the last one.

I have tried and make a for loop that starts in the middle of the user_input and is supposed to put in each letter in the string "right".

```
int main() {

    char user_input[STRING_LENGTH] = { 0 };
    char left[STRING_LENGTH];
    char right[STRING_LENGTH];

    int lenght, mid, i;

    printf("Please type in a string: ");

    fgets(user_input, STRING_LENGTH, stdin);
    user_input[strlen(user_input) - 1] = 0;

    lenght = strlen(user_input);
    mid = lenght/2;
    for (i = 0; i < mid; ++i) {
        left[i] = user_input[i];
    }

    for (i = lenght; i < mid; --i) {
        right[i] = user_input[i];
    }
}
```

The expected result if input is 'airplane' would be 'airp - lane'.

Comment: have you tried continuing your index ? ie. for (i=0 ...) followed by right[i] = '-' and then by for(i;i<strlen(user_input);i++)  ? it's just an id at glance

Comment: Why don't you just use `strncpy()` and set `'\0'` at the end of the first string?

Comment: it is not possible to do almost *anything* in C without pointers. There are pointers all over. In your code too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this part:

```
for (i = lenght; i < mid; --i) {
    right[i] = user_input[i];
}
```

What will the content of `right[0]` be in this case? You're copying the right part of the string, but to the wrong place. Try this instead:

```
for (i = mid; i < lenght; i++) {
    right[i-mid] = user_input[i];
}
```

Also, you should null-terminate those arrays. All in all it should look like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < mid; ++i) {
    left[i] = user_input[i];
}
left[mid] = '\0';
for (i = mid; i < lenght; i++) {
    right[i-mid] = user_input[i];
}
right[i-mid] = '\0';
printf("%s-%s", left, right);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem in your last `for` that will never execute its body because you start from `lenght` *down to* `mid` but test "while it's less than `mid`" which is never true.

Change it to:

```
for (i = lenght; i >= mid; --i)
```

... and make sure you *include* `mid`, otherwise the middle character won't be displayed.

Also, note that you don't really need to count backwards in that loop, which is the cause of the bug. You can do:

```
for (i = mid; i < lenght; i++)
```

Finally, as noted by @Blaze in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58415415/1098603), you should fill in `right` at the proper offset by *subtracting* `mid` from the `i` index:

```
right[i-mid] = ...
```